# Where is the restlet guice integration download or maven artifact?

Tags: maven, guice, restlet

Does anybody know where the restlet guice integration that is mentioned on restlet.org here http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/172-restlet/257-restlet/284-restlet.html can be found?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it only exists in SVN, you have to build it yourself.

http://restlet.tigris.org/source/browse/restlet/trunk/incubator/org.restlet.ext.guice/src/org/restlet/ext/guice/

Luckily it is only 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new version now.  It takes a different approach.  Details at: http://tembrel.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/restlet-guice-extension-considered.html